# Migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio. Previously working code now gets 'Cannot find symbol AsyncTask'

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-studio

I am running Android Studio 1.0.1.  I have imported an Eclipse project into an Android Studio project, but I am getting an error during build.  It's a strange error, this code works fine in Eclipse:

```
    public class EDiaryDataSync {

    private void DoesSoftwareNeedToBeUpdated { 
         String sql = "SELECT S.TextID, S.SyncClass, S.Parameter1, S.Parameter2, "//
                        + " S.Parameter3, S.Parameter4, S.Parameter5, S.Parameter6,  S.PostExecuteSQL, S.PostExecuteSQLSuccessful "//
                        + "FROM L_SyncData AS S "//
                        + "WHERE S.Active = 1 "//
                        + "AND DisplayOrder > 0 "//
                        + "ORDER BY S.DisplayOrder";

         Cursor c = DataBaseConnector.query(sql);
         parameters[0] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Parameter1"));
         parameters[1] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Parameter2"));
         parameters[2] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Parameter3"));
         parameters[3] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Parameter4"));
         parameters[4] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Parameter5"));
         parameters[5] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Parameter6"));
         parameters[6] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PostExecuteSQLSuccessful"));
         task = new SendCurrentSoftwareVersion();
         task.execute(parameters);

    }



    public static class SendCurrentSoftwareVersion extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private OnFinishListener onFinishListener = null;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        for (String param : params) {
            param = replacePseudocode(param);
        }

        try {
            // write current to the APDevices table, based on this device, site, and protocol

            logMessage("Started SendCurrentSoftwareVersion");

            String sp_params = GlobalVars.deviceSerialNumber + "|" + GlobalVars.softwareVersion + "|" + params[1];

            logMessage("SendCurrentSoftwareVersion " + params[0] + " " + sp_params);

            SoapPrimitive response = callProcServiceForNoReturn(params[0], sp_params);

            if (response != null) {
                String sResponse = decryptIfNeeded(response.toString());

                if (!sResponse.equals("")) {
                    if (sResponse.toString().contains("Error=")//
                            || sResponse.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("-1")//
                            || sResponse.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                        insertSyncError(sResponse.toString(), params[0], sp_params);
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    insertSyncError("Blank Response", params[0], sp_params);
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                insertSyncError("Null Response", params[0], sp_params);
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            insertSyncError(e.getMessage(), "");
            return false;
        }

        executePostSyncSQLSuccessful(params);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (onFinishListener != null) {
            onFinishListener.onFinish(result);
        }
    }

    protected void setOnFinishListener(OnFinishListener onFinishListener) {
        this.onFinishListener = onFinishListener;
    }

    public interface OnFinishListener extends EventListener {
        public void onFinish(boolean result);
    }
} 

} //end of class EDiaryDataSync
```

Build Errors:

```
C:\Users\kristy.welsh\Documents\SourceCode\CoreProject_AS1\app\src\main\java\com\assistek\ediary\EDiaryDataSync.java:4181: error: cannot find symbol
  public static class SendCurrentSoftwareVersion extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
                                                       ^
 symbol:   class AsyncTask
 location: class EDiaryDataSync
C:\Users\kristy.welsh\Documents\SourceCode\CoreProject_AS1\app\src\main\java\com\assistek\ediary\EDiaryDataSync.java:230: error: incompatible types
                                    task = new SendCurrentSoftwareVersion();
                                           ^
 required: AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>
 found:    SendCurrentSoftwareVersion
```

What's also weird is that this particular AsyncTask has the same signature as other AsynTasks I've extended in this class (not shown here).  Been at this all day now.  I've made sure the build.gradle file is correct, the settings.gradle file is correct, the local properties file is correct.

build.gradle file:

```
  buildscript {
      repositories {
          jcenter()
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
      }
  }

  allprojects {
      repositories {
          jcenter()
      }
  }
```

build.gradle in app folder:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.4'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.4'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-net-2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

**Edit:**  I just rebuilt the project from an new empty Android Studio project and I am getting the same error, so it has nothing to do with my importing the project from Eclipse.

**Edit 2:** I reinstalled Android Studio and rebuilt project from empty one and get the same error.

Comment: have you converted it to use gradle as build system? if so post the build.gradle content as well

Comment: make sure you 'import android.os.AsyncTask;' I tested, there is no problem with my Android stuido

Comment: @bjiang - This file actually has several other internal classes that extend AsyncTask without an error.

Comment: you should also post the build.gradle in your app folder:)

Comment: So something wrong with your Android Studio, try to reinstall it and start with an empty project

Comment: Another victim of AS... I switched back to the good old Eclipse.

Comment: @KristyWelsh this is the gradle file in the root of your project. There should be another one in the your app module

Comment: @Nasir - I posted it.

Comment: @bjiang - I reinstalled and started with empty project, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing this line from the project imports got the project successfully built:

```
import com.assistek.ediary.EDiaryDataSync.SendCurrentSoftwareVersion.OnFinishListener;
```